# What does "Amplify transfer service is running" notification means?

Tags: notifications

I got a notification for an app saying "Amplify transfer service is running." What does this mean?

Comment: Hi, while the question has enough context to be answered, could you mention the device model, and Android version, add a screenshot, and possibly mention the app name to improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

**The app is using [the AWS Amplify Android library](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android) and this notification appears when the app is transferring data from/to its backend AWS services.**

Cross-referencing from Stack Overflow, [Every upload & download getting notification "Amplify transfer service is running"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72869135/2821954) which referenced to a GitHub issue, [#1803 - A notification appears on user devices](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/1803),

> While the transfer is running, we intend to display the foreground service notification to ensure that the transfer continues if the app is backgrounded/killed. Ideally, this foreground notification should only show while transfer(s) are in progress.

According to the relevant [pull request](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/pull/1759), this is due to the [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) imposed since API 26 (Android 8.0) that apps in the background cannot start background services.

> While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's background services, just as if the app had called the services' `Service.stopSelf()` methods.

In normal cases, the notification should disappear after the transfer is completed. However, the library's maintainer also observed a possible bug:

> However, I have observed that even after a transfer completes, the notification continues to display, even if the app itself is killed. This appears to be a bug that our TransferService is not being stopped upon all transfers completing.

In this case, the app's developers need to fix it.